# Python LDIF Parser

Tags: python

I am trying to parse data from a sample LDIF file below.I want to only write the values of 'LoginID' and 'mail' parameters in a csv file.

```
dn: uid=123456789012345,ou=Students,o=system.edu,o=system
LoginId: 0012345
mail: test1@test.edu

dn: uid=543210987654321,ou=Students,o=system.edu,o=system
LoginId: 0067890
mail: test2@test.edu
```

Below is the code that I am having problems compiling

```
import csv
from ldif import LDIFParser

class ParseRecords(LDIFParser):
    def __init__(self,infile,csv_writer):
        self.csv_writer = csv_writer
    def handle(self,dn,entry):
        self.csv_writer.writerow([entry['LoginId'],entry['mail']])

with open('/root/Python_Scripts/LDIF','rb') as infile, open('/root/Python_Scripts/LDIFExtract.csv','wb') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(['LoginId','mail'])
    ParseRecords(infile,csv_writer).parse()
```

When I compile the code, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LDIFExtract.py", line 14, in <module>
    ParseRecords(infile,csv_writer).parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldif.py", line 345, in parse
    self._line = self._input_file.readline()
AttributeError: ParseRecords instance has no attribute '_input_file'
```

Appreciate any help to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the `__init__` function of the class you're inheriting from (LDIFParser), which likely includes something like `self._input_file = infile`. You can run the constructor commands inside your class by calling `LDIFParser.__init__(self, <the arguments that it would use>)` inside the constructor or not overriding the constructor in the first place.

Comment: Oops missed this LDIFParser.__init__(self,infile) .... I realized it just after I posted it... thanks